# Is this C structure assignment statement legal?

Tags: c

Here is a code example followed by my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct st {

    char stringField[100];
    int intField;
};

typedef struct st st;

void test(st *parameterStruct)
{
    st localStruct;
    strcpy(localStruct.stringField, "HELLO");
    localStruct.intField = 5;

    *parameterStruct = localStruct;
}

int main()
{
    st myStruct;
    strcpy( myStruct.stringField, "XXX" );
    myStruct.intField = 9;

    printf("%s,%i\n", myStruct.stringField, myStruct.intField );

    test(&myStruct);

    printf("%s,%i\n", myStruct.stringField, myStruct.intField);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
XXX,9
HELLO,5
```

I was thinking that since the structure 'localStruct' was created inside a function (NOT using malloc) it had local scope and thus the memory locations where it was stored were free to be overridden once the function stopped executing. However, I tried running this sample program and it executed with no issues. I was thinking that the second print statement was going to print gibberish to the screen since I assigned 'myStruct' to local variable 'localStruct' (versus 'localStruct' being dynamically allocated). I know if 'localStruct' had been created using malloc there would be no such issues.

My question: is assigning the structure variable 'myStruct' (a non dynamic local variable) to y by the use of a pointer in the function test okay and safe to do? I hope that the question is clear.

Comment: Well written question with SSCCE, you good sir deserve a +1.

Comment: (Only nitpick: perhaps the title can be improved to something less general?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assignment always copies.

If you did something like `*x = &y` (assuming the types matched - if the parameter was declared as `st** x`, for example), you would be copying the address of `y`, but since `y` will go out of scope soon, that assignment would be unsafe, as you feared.

But since you're doing `*x = y` instead (where the parameter is declared `st* x`), you are copying the content of `y` to `*x`, so even after `y` goes out of scope, the data stored in `*x` should be valid.

Comment: I think you mean `x = &y` not `*x = &y`. At least it fits the question better IMO. Well unless you mean `x` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @luk32 True, but it wouldn't change the address for the outer expression, which wouldn't demonstrate the fact that the assigned expression goes out of scope. That's why I (uncomfortably) handwaved it with "assuming the types were valid".

Comment: Yea, that's true for the example to be *not-working-as-expected* it would need to be `test( st **x )`. It was a little confusing in the 1st form.

Comment: Historical info: structure assignment was standardized in C89, but was not present in K&R1. Every now and then you come across someone who learned from K&R1 and doesn't know about it :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It's safe.

When you assign:

```
*x = y;
```

The members of `y` are copied into the corresponding members of `*x`. It works as if you did a member to member copy yourself.

Answer (score 1):

C allow structure assignment. **Two structures can be assigned if they are of compatible type**. Two structures **declared at the same time** are compatible and structures **declared using the same "structure tag" or the same type name** are also compatible.

In the example you provided, both `*x` and `y` are declared using the same structure type name `st`, both are compatible and hence the assignment `*x = y` is legal. Since `st x` in `main` creates a structure which is of complete type, passing its address to a function is legal. In your function the assignment `*x = y` simply copies the content of local variable `y` to `*x` and this change to `*x` is persist and reflected to `x` in `main`.